# How create a popup on mouseover depending on the item?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to create a popup depending on the item. The text to appear is taken from the database depending on each item.Specifically, I have this code:

```
{foreach $images as $item}
        <div class="icoana" id="container">
                    <a href="{base_url()}assets/image/{$item->code}/{$item->name}" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="{$item->title}"><img  class="icoane" src="{base_url()}assets/image/{$item->code}/{$item->name}"></a>

                    <div class="detalii">
                        <table style="font-size: 25px">
                           <tr><td>Nume:</td><td>{$item->title}</td> </tr>
                           <tr><td>Lungime:</td><td>{$item->width}&nbsp cm</td> </tr> 
                           <tr><td>Latime:</td><td>{$item->height}&nbsp cm</td></tr>
                        </table>   
                    </div>

                    <div class="despre" id="popup"><img src="{base_url()}assets/image/go.jpg" style="weight: 20px; height:20px;" >Mai  multe...</div>

        </div>
{/foreach}
```

and when mouseover `div class="despre"` I want appear a pop-up with text's description stored in `{$item->description}`.                  The pop-up I want to look like this: http://creativeindividual.co.uk/2011/02/create-a-pop-up-div-in-jquery/.I would like a link to an example or source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly, what you need to do is two steps

1) Print out the div description in the php code immediately below the div mentioned.

So your code becomes.

```
{foreach $images as $item}
        <div class="icoana" id="container">
                    <a href="{base_url()}assets/image/{$item->code}/{$item->name}" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="{$item->title}"><img  class="icoane" src="{base_url()}assets/image/{$item->code}/{$item->name}"></a>

                    <div class="detalii">
                        <table style="font-size: 25px">
                           <tr><td>Nume:</td><td>{$item->title}</td> </tr>
                           <tr><td>Lungime:</td><td>{$item->width}&nbsp cm</td> </tr> 
                           <tr><td>Latime:</td><td>{$item->height}&nbsp cm</td></tr>
                        </table>   
                    </div>

                    <div class="despre" id="popup"><img src="{base_url()}assets/image/go.jpg" style="weight: 20px; height:20px;" >Mai  multe...</div>
                    <div class="desc" style="display:hidden">
                          {$item->description} 
                     </div>
        </div>
        {/foreach}
```

2) After that use the same code in the link you provided above and modify the the display part

```
$(function() {

        $('.despre').hover(function(e) {
           //Code to show the popup
           // Modify to use any standard popup library
           // The code below , for now display the desc only.
           $(this).next().show();

        }, function() {
          $(this).next().hide();
        });

      });
```

For now this will show and hide the div. You can use any ToolTip library to actually display the popup

Examples here : http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Regards

Shreyas N